# Pass any component to my modal with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular6, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I want to make a modal popup that is dynamic, and for this I need the content to be a component which can vary.

Currently in my `modal.component.html` I have this:

```
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-backdrop">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-card">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <a></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div #componentPlaceHolder></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my `modal.component.ts` this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
})
export class ModalCComponent implements OnInit{

  @ViewChild('componentPlaceholder', { read: ViewContainerRef }) componentPlaceholder: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want to make a service that contains a method called, for example showModal () and that depending on where it is called, show in the modal one component or another, but I did not manage to do it.
I tried to do `BsModalService` a .show (`ModalCComponent`) but I don't know how to show the custom component in `#componentPlaceHolder. 
How can I show a specific component that passes parameters to the showModal method?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done by using two components (or service and component).

1. The component/service that calls the modalService to open a modal
   that holds the display content (the modal component)
2. The component that has the actual modal template inside

Example of a component that calls the modalService to open a modal using a component as content

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // This has an optional second argument which can pass extra data
    this.modalService.show(ModalComponent);
  }

}
```

More information in the actual documentation:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component